# Decrypt/Decipher text

Tags: php, encryption, base64

Good Day!

This is my first time to ask question here in stackoverflow, cause usually I only read the solutions that has similar problem with mine. So my problem is, I had been given a task to decipher/decrypt the content of an excel file. (By the way i'm using PHP Language). I queried many times the encyrpt/decrypt on google but still failed. What I found somewhat related (well i guess the nearest solution here) is the `base64_encode` and `base64_decode`. To explain more this is my sample encrypted sentence (sentence because it should be resulted as a question)

> V1JSeEhUUDJiaVdrZmJYSllxV3h2K3B1eDZYY2xobEM4QVRBTDhiTEVkU3JGVHVnelZWUUdWNGNyeGVGYXdrQU9DdXV2cFg4SkcxRzBJblRjY2E4SXh4Q21tNXNVZExrUVZFVDF0SFRXMGFTdms3ZTF5NlkvWXhCd2lkbHhBKzhRaSt5MlpzSC9KRVhNa2pZSXFIcnZBPT0=

**I tried the code**

```
$str = "V1JSeEhUUDJiaVdrZmJYSllxV3h2K3B1eDZYY2xobEM4QVRBTDhiTEVkU3JGVHVnelZWUUdWNGNyeGVGYXdrQU9DdXV2cFg4SkcxRzBJblRjY2E4SXh4Q21tNXNVZExrUVZFVDF0SFRXMGFTdms3ZTF5NlkvWXhCd2lkbHhBKzhRaSt5MlpzSC9KRVhNa2pZSXFIcnZBPT0="; 
base64_decode($str);
```

**The Result is:**

> 81y7Vr6Xqh13qRf4/lWLYMVtim98/w5Y6aNegV4FmbWwpHonakWSigYgN928ksjBdsTff1lSVIGQchQnoV5S8Mw0IIszCSUe2+QxHdJ6X875pS52vReRZcBKHmnN5uFH

Which is wrong because it should display a more readable words/sentence. I don't know if I'm just missing anything. Any advice will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

PS: I tried the online bsae64 decoder (https://www.base64decode.org/) and it displays the right words like *Man* -> *TWfu* (vice versa) so I don't know if I'm focusing on a wrong solution or syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure about the encryption algorithm used on the file. If it is encrypted using AES, you might want to know the key.

Apparently an AES, or a Blowfish block. Having the key would be helpful.

Comment: Thank u for comment, but unfortunately, no I don't have any idea how the file was encrypted.

Comment: Do you have the encryption key?

Comment: sorry but no as well. It was just given to me as an excel file.

Comment: @Aciam297 Can you identify how the excel file was exported and/or where it came from? Just ask the person who gave that to you.